# Dialogflow Web Integration not showing Quick Replies and Multiple Replies

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I've created a chatbot using **Dialogflow** and integrated it with **Telegram, Facebook Messenger and Web**.

The response for Dialogflow is created via **Fulfillment** written in Python.

In Telegram and Facebook Messenger I am getting replies as expected for each message from user.

But now when I am trying integration for **Web**, I've noticed that the replies from chatbot **does not show multiple reply messages/lines and Quick Replies**.

Below is screenshot when user say 'Hi' to the chat bot in **Telegram, Facebook Messenger, Web and Dialogflow console** respectively. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

[image: Telegram]  [image: Messenger]  [image: Web]  [image: Console]

Below is the Fulfillment response JSON:

```
{
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "text": {
        "text": [
          "Greetings from Tulsi Village!!!",
          "My name is Appu. I am your virtual assistant.",
          "How can I help you?"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "quickReplies": {
        "quickReplies": [
          "Book",
          "Rooms",
          "Contact",
          "Other"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: hi @Thanthu, I am having an issue with web demo in android. mic button is not working in android app. Could you please help me if you have any idea about this?

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that I have been struggling a bit with defining quick replies for my chatbot and reading your question helped me a lot, regardless of how weird that might sound :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rendering of response depends on the client you are using.
**Telegram, Facebook Messenger**, are able to render the quick-replies and multi-line replies.
But the **web-demo** which you are using does not support these, hence you are not able to see quick-replies and multi-line replies.

If you want to integrate it with a website, you need to design it in such a way that it can render the json response and show it correctly. Web-demo is not designed to render these.